# Проблема ввода чисел в set множество

Tags: python

Задача:
Первая строка содержит целое число, , число студентов, подписавшихся на английскую газету.
Вторая строка содержит номера рулонов этих студентов, разделенные пробелами.
Третья строка содержит количество студентов, подписавшихся на французскую газету.
Четвертая строка содержит номера рулонов этих студентов, разделенные пробелом.

Выведите общее количество студентов, имеющих хотя бы одну подписку.

Пример ввода:

9

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

9

10 1 2 3 11 21 55 6 8

Пример вывода:
13

Количество студентов, имеющих хотя бы одну подписку:
Номера бросков: и находятся в обоих наборах, поэтому они учитываются только один раз.
Следовательно, общее число равно students.

Столкнулся с проблемой что в сет постоянно записываются разные значения цифр в чем проблема?

```
a = int(input())
print(f'a:{a}')
b = set(input())
print(f'set b:{b}')

c = int(input())
print(f'c:{c}')
d = set(input())

print(f'set d:{d}')
print(len((b)|(d)))
```

Comment: и результат функции union выдает: 11 почему?

Comment: 1) что это за " номера рулонов"? Это же не обои. 2) что за "номера бросков"?

Comment: хз перевод такой вывел гугл

Comment: так тогда и пишите "английский не знаю, чушь какая-то в задаче. Вот исходный текст":-)

Comment: отредактировал ответ с пояснением, что именно произошло (сразу дошло до меня, как надо делать, но не сразу дошло, что происходит в вашем коде). Можете принимать ответ теперь (ставить галку под треугольником:-)

Comment: Кстати, заголовок исправил, так как `set` - никак не список (`set` - не `list`:-))

Comment: Благодарствую )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы же не сказали интерпретатору, как строку обрабатывать, вот он вам и обрабатывает её, как набор символов отдельных. В `d` и записаны все неповторяющиеся символы строки - отдельные цифры и пробел.

Рабочий код - ниже. Выводит 13, как и хотели вы.

```
a = int(input())
print(f'a:{a}')
b = set(map(int, input().split()))
print(f'set b:{b}')

c = int(input())
print(f'c:{c}')
d = set(map(int, input().split()))
print(f'set d:{d}')
print(len((b)|(d)))
```